# pip で LightGBM のインストールが出来ない

Tags: python

下記のようにLightGBMをInstallしたかったのですが、エラーが出ており解決方法を検討しております。すいませんがご教示いただけると幸いです。

実行したコード:

```
!pip install lightgbm 
import lightgbm as lgb
```

表示されたエラー:

```
AttributeError: module 'pandas.core.strings' has no attribute 'StringMethods'
```

Comment: 実行環境は Google Colab でしょうか？

Comment: `!pip list | grep 'lightgbm\|pandas'`でLightGBMとpandasのバージョンを調べてみてください。互換性がないバージョンなのかもしれません。

Comment: エラーメッセージは「AttributeError: module 'pandas.core.strings' has no attribute 'StringMethods'」が全てですか？

Comment: もしdaskがインストールされているなら、そのバージョンも調べてみてください。
`!pip list | grep 'lightgbm\|pandas\|dask\|distributed'`
次のようなissueが上がっています： https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/5739#issuecomment-1500809138

Answer (score 0):

Google ColabのPython3/CPUにて動作確認致しました。

[Colab 上で試したコード:](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1uLDMj30pkaNeMe00Z4bQZJ2oQ9OdWMcV?usp=sharing)

```py
!pip install lightgbm
import lightgbm as lgb

print("No problem.")
```